# Please assist with SQL XML Connection string in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, connection-string

Im trying to connect to database XML called "Connection" stored in the App directory. It connects properly when I hard code it like this

```
const string FILENAME = @"C:\Users\Welman\Desktop\WpfApp2\Connection.xml";
```

I don't want to hard code it because I want it to be always accessible no matter what.So Im using the App Domain like so:

```
  string FILENAME = File.ReadAllText(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Connection.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
       
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string conn = xdoc.Descendants("connectionStrings").FirstOrDefault().Value;

        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn);
```

Its not working and my App gives me an:

> unhandled exception

Perhaps I shoud use XDocument.Parse? I am unfamiliar though.

Comment: Show us your XML

Comment: If it's working when you hard code the path and not when using `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, then you should put a break point at your line with `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` and verify the directory it's pointing to is in fact where you have your `Connection.xml` file. Also, if you post the actual error message you may get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change that code snippet like this.

- It will allow you to check the fully qualified path correctness.
- There is no need to call the `File.ReadAllText()` at all.

**c#**

```
string FILENAME = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Connection.xml");

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
string conn = xdoc.Descendants("connectionStrings").FirstOrDefault().Value;

SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn);
```

Comment: The OP's code very first line does exactly that.